# How to compare if arrays hold the same items in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have a field `items` which is an array with 0 or more items. I want to find all documents that have a specific set of items. They should only have those items and no additional items. The order of the items is undefined.

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "items": ["foo", "bar", "qux"]
}
{
  "_id": 2,
  "items": ["bar", "qux"]
}
{
  "_id": 3,
  "items": ["foo", "bar", "qux", "biz"]
}
{
  "_id": 4,
  "items": ["foo", "qux", "bar"]
}
```

Is there a query operator that can be used on `items` to get all documents that have (only) "foo", "bar" and "qux"? So document 1 and 4 in this example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it with [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) and [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/size/#op._S_size)

```
db.collection.find({items: {$all: ["foo", "qux", "bar"], $size: 3}});
```